# How to make the default Blazor server app template in Visual Studio to be RTL?

Tags: blazor

I want to make the default Blazor template to be RTL without using `dir='rtl'` because it causes some conflicts with DevExpress components. Also, I want to make the `RenderBody`area to be horizontally scrollable when the width of the screen is small?
How can I achieve them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `bootstrap.rtl` instead of general bootstrap. So your `_Layout.cshtml` will have below stylesheet ref:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/bootstrap-grid.rtl.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/bootstrap-reboot.rtl.min.css" />
```

You can also use [RTLCSS](https://rtlcss.com/learn/getting-started/why-rtlcss/). Instead of authoring two sets of CSS files, one for each language direction. Now you can author the LTR version and RTLCSS will automatically create the RTL counterpart for you.

```
  .example {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px 15px 20px;
  margin: 5px 10px 15px 20px;
  border-style: dotted dashed double solid;
  border-width: 1px 2px 3px 4px;
  border-color: red green blue black;
  box-shadow: -1em 0 0.4em gray, 3px 3px 30px black;
}
```

Will be transformed into:

```
  .example {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 20px 15px 10px;
  margin: 5px 20px 15px 10px;
  border-style: dotted solid double dashed;
  border-width: 1px 4px 3px 2px;
  border-color: red black blue green;
  box-shadow: 1em 0 0.4em gray, -3px 3px 30px black;
}
```

If you need both LTR and RTL on the same page, then you can use [RTLCSS String Maps](https://rtlcss.com/learn/usage-guide/string-map/).

For Horizontal scrolling, you can use virtualize component and some JavaScript codes as mentioned in [this link](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/28813#issuecomment-905175717).